# Разбить строку на ассоциативный массив по нескольким ключевым словам из списка

Tags: php, регулярные-выражения

Задача, это получить из строки "1 день 2 часа 15 минут 10 секунд" количество секунд для установки таймера. Причем в строке может быть любая комбинация составляющих. В идеале я вижу решение в получении регулярным выражением массива из 4 элементов независимо от содержания строки. Далее каждый элемент массива будет умножен на количество секунд в сутках, часах и минутах.
Сейчас у меня не получается массив с фиксированным положением элементов, но по именам ключей я всё же могу посчитать секунды. Прошу предложить более изящное решение.

```
$t='2 часа 15 минут';
$parts = preg_split("/(?<=\s|^)(день|дня|дней|час|часа|часов|минут|минута|минуту|минуты|секунд|секунда|секунду|секунды)(?=\s|$)/", $t,-1, PREG_SPLIT_DELIM_CAPTURE);

$s=0;
for ($i = 0; $i <= count($parts)-2; $i+=2) {
     if (stripos($parts[$i+1], 'д') === 0) { $s+=trim($parts[$i])*86400; }
 elseif (stripos($parts[$i+1], 'ч') === 0) { $s+=trim($parts[$i])*3600; } 
 elseif (stripos($parts[$i+1], 'м') === 0) { $s+=trim($parts[$i])*60; } 
 elseif (stripos($parts[$i+1], 'с') === 0) { $s+=trim($parts[$i]); } 
}

echo $s;
```

Добавляю: уже были даны очень хорошие советы по условию задачи. Но конкретно в моем случае цифры могут быть прописью.

Comment: [Укажите](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/posts/1445380/edit) в метках язык программирования.

Comment: ([0-9]{0,2}.(дня|Дней|день))*.([0-9]{0,2}.(часа|часов|час)).... При помощи такой регулярки можно разбить на группы и дальше их обрабатывать отдельно. Но принципиально от Вашего решения мало чем отличается

Comment: @Vadik Очевидно же, что php)))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Можно все варинты дней поменять на day, часы, часов... на hour и тд. И воспользоваться strtotime. Кстати, можно писать даже недели и года :)

```
echo date('c') ."\n";                                      // 2022-09-03T15:33:15+00:00
echo date('c', strtotime('+1 day 2 hour 15 min 10 sec'));  // 2022-09-04T17:48:25+00:00
```

соответственно, кол-во секунд

```
strtotime('+1 day 2 hour 15 min 10 sec') - time()
```

Comment: Идея отличная, но, к сожалению, цифры у меня могут быть прописью. И после разбиения я преобразую слова в цифры.

Comment: И что это меняет - сделайте из прописных обычные

Comment: И правда, переписал свой код под использование strtotime() Спасибо за идею!